# separate two sets of code

Tags: java, components

How to separate the components from the sql method? I need to get this set of code  separated from the rest. I am having difficulty because it linked.

```
 Component droplabel = new DropTargetTextArea("test", "testing");

JLabel cellLabel = new JLabel(icon);

            JPanel cellPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            cellPanel.add(cellLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            cellPanel.add(droplabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            gridPanel.add(cellPanel);
```

////full code

```
connection = getConnection();
try {  
statement = (PreparedStatement) connection
.prepareStatement("select image from image");
 result = statement.executeQuery();
while (result.next()) {
byte[] image = null;
image = result.getBytes("image");

Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(image);
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);

 Component droplabel = new DropTargetTextArea("test", "testing");

JLabel cellLabel = new JLabel(icon);

            JPanel cellPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            cellPanel.add(cellLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            cellPanel.add(droplabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            gridPanel.add(cellPanel);

}

}
```

Comment: Read about `MVC` pattern, that will save your life.

Comment: Also, why are the images stored in a database and not simply on disk?

Comment: i need them to be stored in a database. its a requirement for the assignment

Comment: The `Model View Control Pattern` is going to be helpful here, but my first step towards separation would be to create a separate class for the main GUI components and then have a method that allows you to update the current icon on the GUI and call that from you bit where the image retrieved. This would give you the `Model` and the `View` components of the pattern. It should then more become obvious what the controller is for.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have two tasks here:

1. Retrieve a set of images from the underlying database. I say set because you are using a while-loop for iterating over a ResultSet.

   ```
   connection = getConnection();
   try {  
       statement = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement("select image from image");
       result = statement.executeQuery();
       while (result.next()) {
           byte[] image = null;
           image = result.getBytes("image");
       }
   }
   ```

   You could extract this code to a separate method and use an byte-array to store the retrieved information. This array would be the return-value of the method.
2. Creating ImageIcons and using them in JLabels

   ```
   Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(image);
   ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
   Component droplabel = new DropTargetTextArea("test", "testing");
   JLabel cellLabel = new JLabel(icon);

   JPanel cellPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
   cellPanel.add(cellLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
   cellPanel.add(droplabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   gridPanel.add(cellPanel);
   ```

   This code could also be moved to a separate method. The method retrieves an array of images (or only one depending on your setup) and created the ImageIcon.

Comment: but then it doesnt recognise the variable image in this line of code               Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(image);

Comment: does anyone if i make an array of labels and load the images in there will solve the problem? also does anyone know how to implement this?

Comment: If you are splitting up your code into two methods, the second one could look like `private void addLabels(byte[] images){...}`. Within this method you would do something like `Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(images[0]);` This is not nice code, but should give you an impression of what I thought.

Answer (score 0):

First a little Tip: you should read about JPA and MVC. 
Now to your code: Make a new class and give her a name like "DatabaseHelper" and then put your whole JDBC-Code in a method like "getAllImages()" and make a container class (POJO) for the Image. For the first term this should help you but on the long term you should use JPA and MVC.